# Implicit conversions with functions

Tags: c++, bazel

I am wondering if there is any way that the following code would work rather than say the "is_blockable" is not a member of the class. I am thinking that it would ideally know to convert to the object that has the function.

I am using MSVC on Windows 10 with bazel 4.0 and c++ 11.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <system_error>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

class net {
public:
    bool is_blockable();
};

bool net::is_blockable() {
    return true;
}

template<typename T>
class expect
{

    // MEMBERS
    std::error_code code_;
    typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type storage_;
    // MEMBERS

    T& get() noexcept
    {
        assert(has_value());
        return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(std::addressof(storage_));
    }

    T const& get() const noexcept
    {
        assert(has_value());
        return *reinterpret_cast<T const*>(std::addressof(storage_));
    }

    template<typename U>
    void store(U&& value) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible<T, U>())
    {
        new (std::addressof(storage_)) T{std::forward<U>(value)};
        code_ = std::error_code{};
    }

    void maybe_throw() const
    {
    }

public:
    using value_type = T;
    using error_type = std::error_code;

    expect() = delete;

    operator T&() {
        if (has_value()) {
            return get();
        }
    }

    /*! Store an error, `code`, in the `expect` object. If `code` creates a
    `std::error_code` object whose `.value() == 0`, then `error()` will be set
    to `::common_error::kInvalidErrorCode`. */
    expect(std::error_code const& code) noexcept
      : code_(code), storage_()
    {
    }

    //! Store a value, `val`, in the `expect` object.
    expect(T val) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>())
      : code_(), storage_()
    {
        store(std::move(val));
    }

    expect(expect const& src) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<T>())
      : code_(src.error()), storage_()
    {
        if (src.has_value())
            store(src.get());
    }

};

int main() {

    net n;
    expect<net> e (n);

    e.is_blockable();
}
```

I previously asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67450897/implicit-conversion-on-windows-c?noredirect=1#comment119222266_67450897) where the problem was substituting the expect instance for an integer and then using it in a summation. I don't see why this is any different (i.e. it is a context where an object of another type is expected).

```
<source>(89): error C2039: 'is_blockable': is not a member of 'expect<net>'
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not how conversions work. When calling a member function of an object it's really calling on that object. You can overload the `->` operator to return a reference to the wrapped object (which means you could to `e->is_blockable()`) but not using implicit conversion.

Comment: `operator T&()` doesn't return a value in all cases.

Comment: As a possible reason for not allowing such conversions, it would lead to ambiguity if both the wrapper and the wrapped class had a member function of the same name.

Comment: Ahh thats a shame. I am trying to figure out how this code I am working with ever compiled doing these things... Thank you!